# How to create script shell to execute class name in TestNg By jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

I would like to launch some test By Script Shell in Jenkins, I use TestNG and selenium web driver. The object is to launch one class name in TestNG not all tests.

I write in jenkins this command Script shell :

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG "com.az.tests.TNR_Production_TestsA" testng.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `-testclass` command line parameter to pass the set of test classes.

Quoting the documentation here for quick reference.

> A comma-separated list of classes that can be found in your classpath.

So your shell script would look like

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\lib\*;F:\Selenium\SampleTestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG -testclass com.az.tests.TNR_Production_TestsA
```

For more information please refer to the official documentation [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng).